# Date time stamp Outlook calendar entry automatically?

Tags: outlook

I use Outlook 2007 calendar to schedule appointments.  Is there a way to automatically date time stamp each appointment card as it is created?  I want to know what time I created an appointment without having to manually enter it time.

Answer (score 2):

This took forever for me to figure out.  While Zoredache has an answer that will work, here's another way. For Outlook 2007:

1. Open Outlook
2. Click on "Calendar" in the left side menu
3. At the top of the screen, Click on "View"
4. Move pointer to "Current View"
5. Click on either "All Appointments" or "Active Appointments"
   a. Your appointments should now change from Calendar View and be displayed in as a list.
   b. Your items will be sorted by either "Subject, Location, Start, End," etc.
6. Right click on the bar that displays "Subject, Location, Start, End," etc.
7. Click on "Customize Current View..."
8. A new window will open.  Click on "Fields"
9. Under "Available fields:" click on "Created"
10. Then click "Add->"
11. Then click "Ok"
12. Clik "OK" again.

And you're finished!  Now sort the items as you want, find the item in question, and you'll find the date created under the Created field.

GOOD LUCK!

Answer (score 0):

The already is a property on an Outlook Appointment item named **Created** that will have the timestamp from when the item is created.  I don't have Outlook 2007 in front of me so I cannot tell you how to easily view that property.

In Outlook 2003 if you are looking at the folder view of a calendar and you choose the 'Events' view you can right click on the column headings, select the **Field Chooser** and then Add the **Created** column.

You should be able to create a custom Form using the form-designer and add the Created field somewhere on a Form based on the Appointment Item form.

Comment: This will not work as Outlook recreated appointments as it processes incoming meeting updates.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open the appointment
2. Click the round button (file) top left corner
3. Click Properties
4. Last modified will give you the date and time of entry